# Do toddlers have to learn what they feel?

Tags: behavior, cognitive-development

In Thomas Metzinger's book *Being No One*, he claimed at the start of section 6.3.3

> Have you ever seen a child, who has just learned to walk, run toward a set of two or three stairs much too fast and then fall on its face in an unprotected way, which might have caused considerable injury had it been an adult? The child, now lying face down, lifts its head, turns around, and searches for its mother. It does so with a completely empty facial expression, showing no kind of emotional response. It looks into its mother’s face to find out how it is actually now feeling itself. How bad was it really? Should I cry or should I laugh?

Is that real? I've never seen it. Has this been documented in the literature?